# How to convert 2D matrix of RGBA tuples into PIL Image?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Suppose if I have image `img` with contents:

```
[[(255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255)],
 [(0, 0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255)],
 [(0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255)],
 [(0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255, 255)]]
```

Is there's any way I can make PIL Image from it?

I tried `Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img))` and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4), <i4
```

How can I resolve it? Also is there's any solution without the usage of `numpy` module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Image.fromarray(np.array(img), mode="RGBA")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this (quite self explanatory from [the doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer)):

```
from PIL import Image

arr = np.array(img)
PIL_image = Image.frombuffer('RGBA',(arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]),np.uint8(arr.reshape(arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1],arr.shape[2])),'raw','RGBA',0,1)
```

Comment: It doesn't meet my expectations, it produces a blank image using the data in the question.

Comment: @JimmyYang What mode is your image? Is it not 'RGBA'? Try my update on post. Might be datatype issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set dtype of an array as np.uint8 to let the Image object generator know the format of input data. And I would also recommend to specify the mode because I don't know how PIL choose between RGBA and CMYK when there are 4 channels. The solution is here:

```
from PIL import Image
    
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img, dtype=np.uint8), mode='RGBA')
```